# SonarQube: Illegal characters in path

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube for code analysis in my azure build pipelines. During my last check-in I get an error message: "Illegal characters in path" without any hint about the location of the problem:

```
##[error]Unhandled Exception:
##[error]System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.ProjectInfoExtensions.<>c.<GetAllAnalysisFiles>b__8_0(String path)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Shim.PropertiesFileGenerator.ToProjectData(IGrouping`2 projectsGroupedByGuid)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Shim.PropertiesFileGenerator.TryWriteProperties(PropertiesWriter writer, IEnumerable`1& allProjects)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Shim.PropertiesFileGenerator.GenerateFile()
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PostProcessor.PostProcessor.GenerateAndValidatePropertiesFile(AnalysisConfig config)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PostProcessor.PostProcessor.Execute(String[] args, AnalysisConfig config, IBuildSettings settings)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.PostProcess()
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.<Execute>d__8.MoveNext()
---
```

I have already elevated the verbosity to find the problem:

```
extraProperties: |
  sonar.verbose=true
  sonar.log.level.app=TRACE
  sonar.log.level.web=TRACE
  sonar.log.level.ce=TRACE
  sonar.log.level.es=TRACE
```

But didn't get more information. Is there any better switch that prints out the location of the problem?